# count and check json query result

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I am handling three scenarios :

1) If query returns no result
2) if query returns one result
3) if query returns two or more result

This is my query :

```
$events = DB::table('bookings')
             ->join('events','bookings.event_id','=','events.id')
             ->join('spots','bookings.spot_id','=','spots.id')
             ->join(DB::raw('(select S.event_id,sum(S.spaces) as sum_spaces from spots S group by S.event_id) d'), function($join)
             {
                $join->on('bookings.event_id', '=', 'd.event_id');
             })
             ->select('bookings.event_id','events.name', 'spots.event_date','d.sum_spaces',
                      DB::raw('COUNT(bookings.event_id) as tb'))
             ->groupBy('bookings.event_id')
             ->get();
```

I get $events in json format like this :

```
[]  = 0
[{"event_id":1,"name":"Yoga","event_date":"2016-05-02","sum_spaces":"450","tb":6}] = 1
[{"event_id":1,"name":"Yoga","event_date":"2016-05-02","sum_spaces":"100","tb":16},{"event_id":2,"name":"Yoga","event_date":"2016-05-02","sum_spaces":"450","tb":6},{"event_id":3,"name":"blah","event_date":"2016-05-02","sum_spaces":"250","tb":6}] = 3
```

If you see that 0,1 and 3. thats what I want to know for a given resultant query. 
I need to check if the above result has how many results. How can I find this

Because this is how I am handling the scenarios :

```
if(empty($events))
{
 //sets default value
}
else if(check if $results have one and only one result)
{
 //Do something
}
else
{
  //here I can handle if $events query have more than one result.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-count) them:

```
$numberOfResults = count($events);
```

Comment: oh wow it was that simple. i was returning and it seemed like a json. so i was wondering how to do a count on a json. but i understand now. its json only when returned to view. Thanks for the solution